# moderncv: "Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item. }" Error

Tags: errors, itemize, moderncv

I am very new to Latex but I thought I would use it for my CV, I am using the `moderncv` template. I keep on getting the error above but only for the last line of this code (the `\end{itemize}}` line).

I can't see what the problem is, it seems exactly the same as the template.

```
\cventry{2016--2017}{\large{Teacher}}{\textsc{School}}{Place}{}{Lots of text and blah blah blah etc.
\newline{}\newline{}
\textsc{Achievements:}
\begin{itemize}[itemsep = 0ex]
    \item 97\% pass rate with grade C or above.
    \item Student placements include:
    \begin{itemize}[itemsep = 0ex]
        \item School
        \item School
        \item School
    \end{itemize}
    \newline{}
\end{itemize}}
```

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!  Try `\end{itemize}` instead of `\end{itemize}}`. If this doesn't help please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem. Starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: The option `[itemsep = 0ex]` needs `\usepackage{enumitem}`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I didn't see that bit :). I changed my answer accordingly and referred to your comment.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer If you want, I delete my answer and let you give the answer.

Answer (score 1):

- Help yourself and others by using **structured code**.
- I proposed some structure.
- For the future, I recommend, that you start by a **simple code with the basic structure** (see the second `\cventry` entry).
- The code that you provide is **not compilable** -- see my code for further questions. This is called an **[MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228)**.

> As [Ulrike Fischer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2388/) points out, the `[itemsep = 0ex]` parts
>   requires the `enumitem` package which people need to guess without an
>   MWE. This (if the `enumitem` package is missing) causes the error that
>   you describe.

---

```
\documentclass{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{casual}
\moderncvcolor{blue}

\firstname{John} % Your first name
\familyname{Smith} % Your last name

\begin{document}

\section{Test Section}

%% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/387356
%\cventry{2016--2017}{\large{Teacher}}{\textsc{School}}{Place}{}{Lots of text and blah blah blah etc.
%\newline{}\newline{}
%\textsc{Achievements:}
%\begin{itemize}[itemsep = 0ex]
%    \item 97\% pass rate with grade C or above.
%    \item Student placements include:
%    \begin{itemize}[itemsep = 0ex]
%        \item School
%        \item School
%        \item School
%    \end{itemize}
%    \newline{}
%\end{itemize}}

\cventry{1}
    {2}
    {3}
    {4}
    {5}
    {6} 

\cventry{2016--2017} %1
    {Teacher} %2
    {School} %3
    {Place} %4
    {5} %5
    {Achievements} %6

\cventry{2016--2017} %1
    {Teacher} %2
    {School} %3
    {Place} %4
    {5} %5
    {
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Achievement A
    \item Achievement B
    \item Achievement C
        \begin{itemize}
        \item Achievement C.1
        \item Achievement C.2
        \item Achievement C.3
        \end{itemize}
    \end{itemize}
    } %6    

\end{document}
```

[image]